# Separate strings and integers in Python

Tags: python

I want to split the strings and the numbers. So if the string that is concatenated would be:

```
Hans went to house number 10 92384 29349
```

It should split the text into:

```
Hans went to house number | 10 | 92384 | 29349
```

I am confused on how to tackle this as split won't work because it will also split Hans | went | to | house | number..

Comment: Do you want to split it into a list or just add | characters to the string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pretty easy with regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Hans went to house number 10 92384 29349"
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=\d+\b)', s)
['Hans went to house number', '10', '92384', '29349']
```

That said your question is confusing, if you want to add the `|` char to the output, simply join the output again:

```
>>> ' | '.join(_)
'Hans went to house number | 10 | 92384 | 29349'
```

If your goal is to implement a function that does the trick, you can write this:

```
def split_numbers(string, join=None):
   from re import split
   split = re.split(r'\s+(?=\d+\b)', string)
   return join.join(split) if join else split
```

Notice that I added the word boundary `\b` on my regex to avoid matching words starting with a number like the `2cups` in the sentence `Hans went to house number 10 92384 29349 and drank 2cups of coffee`

Comment: regular expressions probably the best way to approach this problem

Comment: Let's say it's easy to understand how regular expressions work. And they are powerful. But it isn't that easy to define one ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to add `|` to the string, you can try this:

```
a="Hans went to house number 10 92384 29349"

print(" ".join("| "+i if i.isdigit() else i for i in a.split()))
```

Output:

```
Hans went to house number | 10 | 92384 | 29349
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split your sentence into words, then try to cast the word into integer. If the cast fail, then just concat

```
a = "Hans went to house number 10 92384 29349"
res = ""
for word in a.split():
   try:
      number = int(word)
      res += " | %d" % number
   except ValueError:
      res += " %s" % word
```

---

**Edit:** I tried to give the "simplest" solution. I mean, it is longer, but I guess easier to understand . Still, if you understand other solutions (1 line), go for it.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expression splitting with `re`:

```
import re


txt = 'Hans went to house number 10 92384 29349'

' | '.join(re.split('\s(?=\d)',txt))

# 'Hans went to house number | 10 | 92384 | 29349'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could do it:

```
a = 'Hans went to house number 10 92384 29349'

result = [' '.join([item for item in a.split(' ') if not item.isdigit()])] + [int(item) for item in a.split(' ') if item.isdigit()]
```

And if you want output as you showed:

```
new_result = ' | '.join([str(item) for item in result])
```

Comment: The order of the words is changed when you have an example like `a = 'Hans 12 went to house number 10 92384 29349'`.

Comment: Yes it is. But that wasn't in example. And that same example would break the top voted solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
a = "Hans went to house number 10 92384 29349"

res = []

for item in a.split():
    if item.isdigit():
        res.extend(['|', item])
    else:
        res.append(item)

print(' '.join(res))
#Hans went to house number | 10 | 92384 | 29349
```